# MySQL count of occurrences in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the ff. structure:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| id | player1 | player2 |   win   |    lose |   LEAVE | STATUS |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
|  1 |  151663 |  150000 |  151663 |  150000 |       0 |      1 |
|  2 |  150000 |  151663 |  150000 |  151663 |       0 |      1 |
|  3 |  151663 |  150000 |  151663 |  150000 |       0 |      1 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
```

How do I generate a query if I need a result like below?

```
+--------+-----+------+-------+
| player | win | lose | leave |
+--------+-----+------+-------+
| 150000 |   1 |    2 |     0 |
| 151663 |   2 |    1 |     0 |
+--------+-----+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select player, sum(win) as wins, sum(lose) as losses,
       sum(leave) as leaves
from ((select win as player, 1 as win, 0 as lose, 0 as leave
       from ff
       where win <> 0
      ) union all
      (select lose as player, 0 as win, 1 as lose, 0 as leave
       from ff
       where lose <> 0
      ) union all
      (select leave as player, 0 as win, 0 as lose, 1 as leave
       from ff
       where leave <> 0
      )
     ) wll
group by player;
```

Comment: Perfect one..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Player,sum(win)win,sum(lose)lose,leave FROM(
SELECT win Player,1 as win,0 as lose,leave FROM @Table 
UNION ALL
SELECT lose Player,0 as win,1 as lose,leave FROM @Table
)A group by Player,leave
```